# Conditional Statement in python

Tags: python

How to use multiple conditional statements in python? I have used it like:

```
 if expression:
   elif expression:
     if expression:
```

Comment: please show the attempt that you  given over your question.

Comment: if: elif: elfi:....else:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple conditional statements in Python can be done as follows:

```
if condition1:
    statement
elif condition2:
    statement
elif condition2:
    statement
else:
    statement
```

Or if you wanted nested conditional statements:

```
if condition1:
    if condition2:
       if condition3:
           statement
       else:
           statement
    elif condition4:
       if condition5:
           statement
       else:
           statement
```

(This is just one example of some nested conditional statements)